# F#, SqlDataProvider, and Oracle

Tags: oracle, f#, type-providers

I can connect to my database just fine if I do this

```
let connection = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=hr;Password=hr;Data Source=localhost")
  connection.Open()
```

This, however, will not work

```
#r "FSharp.Data.SqlProvider"
open FSharp.Data.Sql        
type sql = SqlDataProvider<
             ConnectionString = "User Id=hr;Password=hr;Data Source=localhost",
             DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ORACLE,
             ResolutionPath = "C:\apps\Oracle\product\12.1.0",
             Owner = "hr">
```

The compiler says:

> The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error:
>   Exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
>   was thrown.

My best guess is a problem with my ResolutionPath.  The ResolutionPath I've pasted here is to my Oracle client.  I've also tried a ResolutionPath of [OracleClient]\bin and gotten the same result.

Answer (score 3):

The resolution path of your Oracle should point to Oracle's ODP.NET (Oracle Data Provider for .NET), instead of common installation path of Oracle Database of Oracle 12c. Because basic installation of Oracle database since Oracle 11g and then 12c can't be guaranteed to include ODP.NET installation properly. Also ODP.NET installation is independent of any Oracle database installation on your machine.

You can download ODP.NET by going to Oracle Data Access (ODAC) for Windows page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Then download the ODP.NET provider for your specific needs, either 32 or 64 bit.
Install the latest ODP.NET, and then point the `ResolutionPath` to the path of ODP.NET installation, especially the folder that contains common DLL of ODP.NET.

Let me know if you still have problems. Good luck!

Comment: I followed the link and downloaded the ODP.NET_Managed...zip, then unzipped and followed install instructions.  No Dice.  If I try the other provider types - MSSQL or POSTGRESQL then I get errors that make more sense - they will say things like "could not connect" or could not find "foo.dll".  Seems there is something inherently broken with trying to use Oracle.

Comment: @JordanWilcken I know this is an old post but are you still having issues? I had a lot of trouble getting the SqlDataProvider to work with Oracle but I finally got it going. If I were you, I would try using a Visual Studio project instead of interactive mode. I didn't end having to use the ResolutionPath argument -- I just installed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess into my project with NuGet.

Comment: @JordanWilcken have you checked your tnsnames.ora config file? please ensure that it is correct, and also ensure that oracle home path is set.

Answer (score 0):

The key `UserId` needs to have a space between "User" and "Id", just like in your working connection string.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad paste on my part.  The SqlDataProvider did have a space between "User" and "Id" in my code.  Doesn't work.